# Paralist environment

Tags: lists, paralist

I'm using `paralist` environment in this form:

```
\begin{compactenum}[(a)]
\item  Results with no change in the statement (except the
replacement of $[a,\infty]$ for $[a,b]$):
\begin{compactitem}
\item Theorem  (Linearity and Positivity).
\item Theorem (Additivity). 
\item Lemma  (Cauchy Criterion). 
We remark that in some cases a
change or supplementary argument is demanded in the proof.
\end{compactitem}
\item Results with a minor change in the statement:
\begin{compactitem}\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
\item Theorem (Second Mean Value Theorem). \item
Theorem  (Integration by Substitution).
\end{compactitem}
\end{compactenum}
```

I would like to ask how to put the sentence: *"We remark that in some cases a
  change or supplementary argument is demanded in the proof"* on the same level as *"Result with no change..."*.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that by simply moving that item outside the inner `compactitem` since you want it at the same level as the outside `compactitem`:

[image]

### Note:

- A separate `\item []` is not necessary for this as you are just continuing the prior `\item` from the outer `compactitem`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist} 
%
\begin{document}
\begin{compactenum}[(a)]
\item  Results with no change in the statement (except the
replacement of $[a,\infty]$ for $[a,b]$):
\begin{compactitem}
\item Theorem  (Linearity and Positivity).
\item Theorem (Additivity). 
\item Lemma  (Cauchy Criterion). 
\end{compactitem}
We remark that in some cases a
change or supplementary argument is demanded in the proof.
\item Results with a minor change in the statement:
\begin{compactitem}\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
\item Theorem (Second Mean Value Theorem). \item
Theorem  (Integration by Substitution).
\end{compactitem}
\end{compactenum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jane: Please updated solution -- you don't need to use `item []`.

Answer (score 6):

Note that an equivalent output is obtainable via the more flexible [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). Indeed, it provides a `nosep` option to all its lists that removes all vertical spacing and allows for a compact presentation, similar to that provided by `compactitem` and `compactenum` of [`paralist`](http://ctan.org/pkg/paralist).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),nosep]
  \item  Results with no change in the statement (except the 
    replacement of $[a,\infty]$ for $[a,b]$):
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
      \item Theorem (Linearity and Positivity).
      \item Theorem (Additivity). 
      \item Lemma (Cauchy Criterion). 
    \end{itemize}
    We remark that in some cases a
    change or supplementary argument is demanded in the proof.
  \item Results with a minor change in the statement:
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
      \item Theorem (Second Mean Value Theorem).
      \item Theorem (Integration by Substitution).
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The options `nosep` (or less-compact `noitemsep`) can be set globally, or used locally (as above) on a list-by-list basis.